# Coded UI Automation is not working with Silverlight 5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0, coded-ui-tests

I am using Coded UI (VS2013) for my sliverlight OOB UI (VS2010) automation. Once i start recording and i put mouse cursor on any control in SL OOB UI then i am getting below error. I also noticed many people faced this issue. But i didn't find any solution for this.

**EDIT**:
I've added [SilverlightUIAutomationHelper](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CCommon%20Files%5Cmicrosoft%20shared%5CVSTT%5C12.0%5CUITestExtensionPackages%5CSilverlightUIAutomationHelper%5Cv5.0%5CMicrosoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper.dll) to SL OOB application (VS2010).
I've added below dlls for Coded UI project.
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMicrosoft%20Visual%20Studio%2012.0%5CCommon7%5CIDE%5CPublicAssemblies%5CMicrosoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll) and
[Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Silverlight.dll](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CCommon%20Files%5Cmicrosoft%20shared%5CVSTT%5C12.0%5CUITestExtensionPackages%5CMicrosoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Silverlight.dll)

[image]

Comment: have you added UIAutomationHelper.dll to your application ?? if not please do so compile it again and deploy it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I've added. it is in xap as well.

Comment: Solution is install VS2015 Enterprise version... it works well